# node.js empty reply from the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I have developed an API using node.js. In my local system API is running at port 2100, and i used the following curl command

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:2100/xx/yy/zzz
```

And i received the following response:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>       X-Powered-By: Express
>       Vary: Accept-Encoding
>       WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Users"
>       Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3A-qD8JTJTLNTnbc0bv2YsTcd2.sfJK8%2FOFan26l8QhuS4oxyEvUtGvhztevEcWX51kceE;
>   Path=/; HttpOnly
>       Date: Wed, 06 May 2015 09:31:30 GMT
>       Connection: keep-alive
>       Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Because i am using authorization i received the above response.

But in my production system i used the same curl command but i am receiving

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

I dont know whats happening? I searched a lot but i cant find a solution. Please share your ideas.

EDIT:

MY API has crashed due to this error:

> Exception: Error setting TTL index on collection : sessions",

MY code:

```
app.use(express.session({
            secret: 'MEAN',
            store: new mongoStore({
                url: config.dbmongo.db,//db
                collection: 'sessions'
            })
        }));
```

Can you please explain what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to help you without any code, could be a million things wrong

Comment: @Yang Li Thanks for your time. My question is whether this is some http permission problem or problem in my code??

Comment: The unauthorized response is because of your code.  The Empty reply from server could be anything, it could be ur using the wrong address, or ur server crashed or just about a  million other possibilities..?

Answer (score 1):

You should be start listening after the db is connected. It might possibly be the issue.

Answer from [github](https://github.com/diversario/connect-mongostore/issues/26#issuecomment-59820748)

```
mongoose.connect.on('connected', function () {
   var server = app.listen(app.get('port')), function () { 
     debug('Express server listening on port %d in mode %s', server.address().port, app.get('env'));
  });
});
```